# The best way to implement the class which answer if coninas and adds elemns

Tags: c#, addition, contains

I am interested in data structure to implement indicator for my data
my data could be preseted as triple of string,string and int

```
public class MyData
{
    public string Key1,
    public string Key2,
    public int Key3
}
```

I want to implement

```
public class MyIndicator
```

whith Methods : 
`IsContained (MyData data)` and

```
Add (MyData data)
```

What is the best and efficient way to implement `MyIndicator` class

Comment: Are you asking how to add methods to a class?

Comment: I am asking for advise how to implement class Indicator

Comment: If you are asking about the storage - probably some kind of `Dictionary<>` will be enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
public class Indicator
{
    List<MyData> _dataList = new List<MyData>();

    public bool IsContained(MyData data)
    {

        return _dataList.Exists(x => x.Key == data.Key 
                                  && x.Key1 == data.Key1
                                  && x.Key2 == data.Key2);
    }

    public void Add(MyData data)
    {
        _dataList.Add(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to compare all 3 keys

Comment: I have edited the code so that it compares all 3 keys now.